# d3.js custom Sankey diagram with Layered Digraph Layout

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, svg, graph

I'm very new to d3.js (and SVG in general), and I want to do something simple: Organizations relationship based on Contracts.

### **Brief intro:**

I am trying to generate a diagram from financial relationships between companies in order to visualize potential fraud based on flow of money. The data is generated by Contracts/Agreements DB. I tried to display what I imagine in my head in the image bellow.

Final Diagram:

[image]

The diagram has 2 main components - Organizations and Contracts.

The diagram begins with an organization. On the right side of it are all the contracts that this organization is paying to. Next is the destination of these payments.

So for example the first row represents how **Apple Inc** is paying **Manufacturing Company Inc** based on contract "*Development of parts for iPhone X under Licence 3.0*". In each contract there are small boxes that represent payments that are made from source to destination company (green means "paid", white means "owed")

### Question

Is there a way this can be chieved with d3.js. Layout and sorting. I have tried to implement this in jQuery and I have major problem with properly sorting each contract so that the links do not mess up.

I used the following examples for starting point but got nowhere:

- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2966094
- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570
- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184

After extensive research I found that there is an term/algorithm called "[Layered Graph Drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing)". In short the idea of the sorting algorithm is to sort all nodes and connections in such a way that there are no crosses (or as minimal as possible)

Please help me out. I searched the internet for days trying to find a solution but with no luck.

Comment: "> Is there a way this can be chieved with d3.js". 

Yes, there is. You have to be consicous that d3.js has a learning curve. Thare the code you have, in order to get some help. 

The diagram you want to generate looks a bit like a Sankey diagram. [d3-sankey](https://github.com/d3/d3-sankey) may be useful, unless you prefer to a dendogram.

Comment: @MehdiElFadil you re right it is closer to Sankey diagram but with a lot of customizations (i guess). The code I have is in jQuery - which I no longer want to use for this. So basically I am starting with a blank canvas here. I was looking for a right path to take. Will look into d3-sankey and post updates if I have